# How to pass a EGLSurface to a Surface in Kotlin (better) or Java?

Tags: opengl-es, arcore, sceneform, egl

I've a stream coming from a RendererThread like this (it's been only made as test)

```
class RendererThread(val surface: SurfaceTexture, mSurface: Surface?) : Thread() {

    var isStopped = false
    var color = 0f
    private lateinit var eglSurface:EGLSurface

    val config = intArrayOf(
        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 0,
        EGL10.EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 0,
        EGL10.EGL_NONE
    )
    var surfacePlane = mSurface
    var surfaceTexImported:SurfaceTexture? = null

    fun getSurfaceTexture(surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture){
        this.surfaceTexImported = surfaceTexture
    }

    fun getSurface(surface: Surface){
        this.surfacePlane = surface
    }

    fun  chooseEglConfig(egl: EGL10, eglDisplay: EGLDisplay) : EGLConfig {
        val configsCount = intArrayOf(0);
        val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1);
        egl.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, config, configs, 1, configsCount)
        return configs[0]!!
    }

    override fun run() {
        super.run()

        val egl = EGLContext.getEGL() as EGL10
        var eglDisplay = egl.eglGetDisplay(EGL10.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        egl.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, intArrayOf(0, 0))   // getting OpenGL ES 2
        val eglConfig = chooseEglConfig(egl, eglDisplay);
        val eglContext = egl.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, eglConfig,
            EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, intArrayOf(
                EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
            ));
        if(this.surfacePlane == null){
            eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, surface, null)
        } else {
            eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, surfacePlane, null)
        }

        var colorVelocity = 0.31f

        print(egl.eglGetError())
        while (!isStopped && egl.eglGetError() == EGL10.EGL_SUCCESS) {
           
            egl.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext)
            colorVelocity *= if (color > 1 && color < 1.6 || color < 0) {
                +1
            } else {
                -1
            }
            color += colorVelocity

            GLES20.glClearColor(color / 2, color, color, 0.5f)
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            egl.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface)

            Thread.sleep((1f / 60f * 1000f).toLong()) // in real life this sleep is more complicated
        }

        surface.release()
        egl.eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, eglContext)
        egl.eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface)
    }
}
```

it should produce a stroboscopic like effect on green, even it atm it is stuck on black, but it doesn't matter since I can see it's working.
It can be easily rendered into a TextureView, however TextureView is not supported by Sceneform in ViewRenderable.

My idea is to pipe the stream into an ExternalTexture given to a ModelRenderable, the same to play a video from MediaPlayer over an augmented image.

So I tried to pass the ExternalTexture's SurfaceTexture (and even being quite "desperate" the Surface) to the EGLSurface constructor.

In both cases as best result I obtain a whole screen color rendered instead of rendering into the Surface of my modelRenderable, built like this

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
        
        .build()
        .thenAccept { liquidRenderable ->
            liquidViewRenderable = liquidRenderable
            liquidRenderable.isShadowCaster = false
            liquidRenderable.isShadowReceiver = false
            liquidRenderable.material.setExternalTexture("videoPlane", externalTexture)
        }
        .exceptionally { throwable ->
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create renderable", throwable)
            return@exceptionally null
        }
```

NOTE:
I changed the previous code part.
I initialise the renderer in the onSurfaceTextureAvailable method available for TextureView class

```
    override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
       renderer = RendererThread(surface)
    } // here the "surface" passed is actually the SurfaceTexture and        not the Surface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to a solution that's indeed pretty easy:

1. create a TextureView into the OnCreate method

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

       ...
       mTextureView = TextureView(this.context)
       ...
   }
   ```
2. link the TextureView to the View in OnViewCreated method

   ```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
       val mViewGroup = view.parent as ViewGroup
       mViewGroup.addView(mTextureView)
       ...
   ```
3. create the

   ```
   externalTexture = ExternalTexture()
   ```

   after the TextureView is fully initialized
4. Take the renderer which works with egl and pass the

   ```
   externalTexture.surface
   ```

   as argument in

   ```
   eglSurface = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, eglConfig, injectedSurface, null) 
   //injectedSurface is the externalTexture.surface
   ```